# Synchronizing Eclipse and github upon repo creation?

Tags: eclipse, git, github

On Eclipse Luna with EGit plugin I want to create a project and use it straightaway with github.

Can a github repo be initiated from inside Eclipse with EGit?

If not, can I use command-line github, and point Eclipse to the locally cloned copy of the repo?

Much hacking around failed to reveal a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the local repo configuration as seen in Egit in order to add a remote named origin, with the url of your GitHub repo.

See "[Repository Configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Repository_Configuration)":

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/e/e2/RepoMgrRemoteConfig.png]